# How can I loop a list of models to get slope estimate

Tags: r, loops, lme4, mixed-models

I have a list of models as specified by the following code:

```r
varlist <- list("PRS_Kunkle", "PRS_Kunkle_e07", 
   "PRS_Kunkle_e06","PRS_Kunkle_e05", "PRS_Kunkle_e04", 
   "PRS_Kunkle_e03", "PRS_Kunkle_e02", "PRS_Kunkle_e01",  
   "PRS_Kunkle_e00", "PRS_Jansen", "PRS_deroja_KANSL")

PRS_age_pacc3 <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {    
    lmer(substitute(z_pacc3_ds ~ i*AgeAtVisit  + i*I(AgeAtVisit^2)  +  
             APOE_score + gender + EdYears_Coded_Max20 +  
             VisNo + famhist + X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 +
             (1 |family/DBID),
       list(i=as.name(x))), data = WRAP_all, REML = FALSE)
})
```

I want to obtain the slope of PRS at different age points in each of the models. How can I write code to achieve this goal? Without loop, the raw code should be:

```
test_stat1 <- simple_slopes(PRS_age_pacc3[[1]], levels=list(AgeAtVisit=c(55,60,65,70,75,80)))
test_stat2 <- simple_slopes(PRS_age_pacc3[[2]], levels=list(AgeAtVisit=c(55,60,65,70,75,80)))
test_stat3 <- simple_slopes(PRS_age_pacc3[[3]], levels=list(AgeAtVisit=c(55,60,65,70,75,80)))
test_stat4 <- simple_slopes(PRS_age_pacc3[[4]], levels=list(AgeAtVisit=c(55,60,65,70,75,80)))
test_stat5 <- simple_slopes(PRS_age_pacc3[[5]], levels=list(AgeAtVisit=c(55,60,65,70,75,80)))
test_stat6 <- simple_slopes(PRS_age_pacc3[[6]], levels=list(AgeAtVisit=c(55,60,65,70,75,80)))
test_stat7 <- simple_slopes(PRS_age_pacc3[[7]], levels=list(AgeAtVisit=c(55,60,65,70,75,80)))
test_stat8 <- simple_slopes(PRS_age_pacc3[[8]], levels=list(AgeAtVisit=c(55,60,65,70,75,80)))
test_stat9 <- simple_slopes(PRS_age_pacc3[[9]], levels=list(AgeAtVisit=c(55,60,65,70,75,80)))
test_stat10 <- simple_slopes(PRS_age_pacc3[[10]], levels=list(AgeAtVisit=c(55,60,65,70,75,80)))
test_stat11 <- simple_slopes(PRS_age_pacc3[[11]], levels=list(AgeAtVisit=c(55,60,65,70,75,80)))
```

Comment: where is `simple_slopes` from? (nvm, looks like `reghelper` package, but would be good to add this to your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(lme4)
library(reghelper)
set.seed(101)
## add an additional factor variable so we can use it for an interaction
sleepstudy$foo <- factor(sample(LETTERS[1:3], size = nrow(sleepstudy),
                         replace = TRUE))
m1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days*foo + I(Days^2)*foo + (1|Subject), data = sleepstudy)
s1 <- simple_slopes(m1, levels=list(Days = c(5, 10, 15)))
```

Looking at these results, `s1` is a data frame with 6 rows (number of levels of `foo` × number of `Days` values specified) and 5 columns (`Days`, `foo`, estimate, std error, t value).

The simplest way to do this:

```r
res <- list()
for (i in seq_along(varlist)) {
   res[[i]] <- simple_slopes(model_list[[i]], ...)  ## add appropriate args here
}
res <- do.call("rbind", res)  ## collapse elements to a single data frame
## add an identifier column
res_final <- data.frame(model = rep(varlist, each = nrow(res[[1]])), res)
```

If you want to be fancier, you could replace the `for` loop with an appropriate `lapply`. If you want to be even fancier than that:

```r
library(tidyverse)
(model_list
  %>% setNames(varlist)
  ## map_dfr runs the function on each element, collapses results to
  ##  a single data frame. `.id="model"` adds the names of the list elements
  ##  (set in the previous step) as a `model` column
  %>% purrr::map_dfr(simple_slopes, ... <extra args here>, .id = "model")
)
```

By the way, I would be very careful with `simple_slopes` when you have a quadratic term in the model as well. The slopes calculated will (presumably) apply only in the case where any other continuous variables in the model are zero.  You might want to center your variables as in Schielzeth 2010 *Methods in Ecology and Evolution* ("Simple means to improve ...")

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you very much! Your code is really helpful! But I have a question for your concern "The slopes calculated will (presumably)...are zero". Suppose I have a interaction model with quadratic term specified as the following y = b1x1+b2x2+b3x2^2+b4x1*x2+b5x1*x2^2. I think once I specify the value of my quadratic moderator (x2 and x2^2), I can get the slope of x1 and the slope is x1(b1+b4*x2+b5*x2^2). I am not sure why you said" the slopes apply ...in the model are zero".. can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: Sorry, I may have overreacted; it's possible that the `simple_slopes` stuff works correctly in this case. I just get nervous whenever anyone is working with a linear term in the presence of higher-order terms in the model.  Just make sure you spot-check a few of the answers to make sure you're getting something sensible/close to what you expected.